# UWP play MediaElement after the source is changed

Tags: c#, uwp

I want the MediaElement called player to play mp3 after specify its source:

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            player.Stop();
            player.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/anata.mp3");
            player.Play();
        }
```

But it does not work, and there is no Error showed. How should I do?

Here is the original question and full code:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:cvt="using:App1"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <cvt:MusicConverter x:Key="mc"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Viewbox Visibility="Visible" Margin="20">
        <Grid x:Name="root" Height="1000" Width="1800">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.15*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.15*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="150" Fill="#FF4187A9" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <MediaElement x:Name="player" MediaFailed="player_MediaFailed" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="Assets/bad_apple.mp4" AutoPlay="false" MediaOpened="Player_Opened" MediaEnded="Player_ended"/>
            <Slider x:Name="controller" Value="{Binding ElementName=player, Path=Position, Converter={StaticResource mc}, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="50" Width="1000" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
            <Button RequestedTheme="Dark" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE112;" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="75" Width="75" Margin="449,0,0,0" Click="Button_Click_3"/>
            <Button RequestedTheme="Dark" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE111;" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="75" Width="75" Margin="750,0,0,0" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
            <Button x:Name="playButton" RequestedTheme="Dark" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="75" Width="75" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click_1">
                <SymbolIcon x:Name="ppp" Symbol="Play" />
            </Button>
            <Slider x:Name="vol" StepFrequency="0.05" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="1.0" SmallChange="0.05" LargeChange="0.1" Value="0.5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="30" Width="100" Margin="1019,42,167,43" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"/>
            <ToggleSwitch x:Name="repeatButton" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  OnContent="repeat on" OffContent="repeat off" IsOn="False" Margin="45,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="PlayList" FontSize="72" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="140,27,1146,0"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="#ffffff"/>
            <ListBox x:Name="lst" SelectedIndex="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="0,155,0,0" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
                <TextBlock Text="Bad Apple" FontSize="50" />
                <TextBlock Text="Anata" FontSize="50" />
                <TextBlock Text="Wind" FontSize="50" />
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>

</Page>
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;


namespace App1
{
    class MusicConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return ((TimeSpan)value).TotalSeconds;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)value);
        }
    }
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement();
            var synth = new Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();
            Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("button");
            mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
            mediaElement.Play();
        }

        private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int sel = lst.SelectedIndex;
            string videoName;
            switch (sel)
            {
                case 0:
                    videoName = "bad_apple.mp4"; break;
                case 1:
                    videoName = "anata.mp3"; break;
                case 2:
                    videoName = "Wind.mp3"; break;
                default:
                    videoName = "bad_apple.mp4"; break;
            }
            player.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/" + videoName);

        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (player.CurrentState.ToString()=="Paused")
            {
                player.Play();
                ppp.Symbol = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Symbol.Pause;
                Debug.WriteLine(player.CurrentState.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                player.Pause();
                ppp.Symbol = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Symbol.Play;
                Debug.WriteLine(player.CurrentState.ToString());
            }

        }

        private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            player.Volume = (double)vol.Value;
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            lst.SelectedIndex = (lst.SelectedIndex + 1) % lst.Items.Count;
            Debug.WriteLine(player.CurrentState.ToString());
        }

        private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            lst.SelectedIndex = (lst.SelectedIndex - 1) < 0 ? lst.Items.Count - 1 : lst.SelectedIndex - 1;
        }
        private void Player_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { 
            controller.Maximum = player.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
        }
        private void Player_ended(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (repeatButton.IsOn)
            {
                player.Play();
            }
            else
            {
                lst.SelectedIndex = (lst.SelectedIndex + 1) % lst.Items.Count;
                int sel = lst.SelectedIndex;
                string videoName;
                switch (sel)
                {
                    case 0:
                        videoName = "bad_apple.mp4"; break;
                    case 1:
                        videoName = "anata.mp3"; break;
                    case 2:
                        videoName = "Wind.mp3"; break;
                    default:
                        videoName = "bad_apple.mp4"; break;
                }
                player.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/" + videoName);
                player.Play();
            }
            player.Play();
        }

        private void player_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string msg = e.ErrorMessage;
            Debug.WriteLine(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

The main question is `Player_ended`. I want this player can repeat when the `repeatButton` is on, and play next mp3 automatically when it is off. But it can't work. The `Source` is changed to new Uri successfully, but the code `player.Play()` seems like to be ignored. I must click `playButton` to play. I simplify the code and I get a new question, which is showed on the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following:

1. Check if the computer has sound turned on
2. Check whether the music file URL is correct (and whether the file can be played by other players)

If everything is normal, you can listen to the `MediaElement.MediaFailed` event. If it triggers, it indicates that the music file may be abnormal. You can get more information about the error from the event.

```cs
private void player_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string msg = e.ErrorMessage;
    Debug.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

By the way, in Windows 10, build 1607 and on we recommend that you use [MediaPlayerElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/media-playback#create-a-media-player) in place of `MediaElement`. `MediaPlayerElement` has the same functionality as `MediaElement`, while also enabling more advanced media playback scenarios. Additionally, all future improvements in media playback will happen in `MediaPlayerElement`.

---

**Update**

The problem with your code is that you are calling `Play()` method at the wrong time.

After setting the Source for the `player`, the `player` will enter the **Opening** state. When you call `Play()` while the `player` is in this state, the player cannot play audio, and when the music file is loaded, it naturally enters the `Pause` state.

So you can delete the `player.Play()` method at the end of `Player_ended`, just set `player.AutoPlay = True;`

like this:

```cs
private void Player_ended(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (repeatButton.IsOn)
    {
        player.Play();
    }
    else
    {
        lst.SelectedIndex = (lst.SelectedIndex + 1) % lst.Items.Count;
        player.AutoPlay = true;
    }
}
```

By the way, When you modify `lst.SelectedIndex`, the `ListBox_SelectionChanged` event is also triggered, you do not have to call it again in `Player_ended`.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have checked these questions, and all they are normal, MediaFailed doesn't be called. After I click this button, I must click a play button to play this mp3.

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce your problem, can you show the full code (including xaml), or you might consider setting `MediaElement.AutoPlay` property to `True`

Comment: The code is just ```player.Play();```, and the result of ```Debug.WriteLine(player.CurrentState.ToString());``` is ```Paused``` instead of ```Playing```, but the mp3 is actually playing.

Comment: I have added my full code, sorry for my poor English (｡•́︿•̀｡)